# What can you do while nauseated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Follow up on [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59766/3101) on the alchemist's stink bomb.

This bomb produces a stink cloud which, if you fail your save roll, will leave you nauseated.

> Creatures with the nauseated condition experience stomach distress. Nauseated creatures are unable to attack, cast spells, concentrate on spells, or do anything else requiring attention. The only action such a character can take is a single move action per turn.

In a game, a creature was nauseated but used acrobatics as part of its one move to jump over us blocking the exit and started to 'run' away.

Can you use acrobatics (or any other non-action-using skill) when you are nauseated? Does it fall under the 'anything else requiring attention'? What is an as close to exhaustive as possible list of things you *can* do when nauseated?

It sure does feel funny having a creature with stomach aches, so painful it can't even attack, jumping all over the place...

Comment: Possibly related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51155/can-you-use-swift-or-free-actions-whilst-nauseated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no definition of actions requiring "attention", so I believe it's safe to assume that sentence to be descriptive. 
This means that there are two limits :

- single move action per turn
- Can't attack or cast spells

Anything not included in these categories is doable.

Regarding the specific acrobatic case:

> Action: None. An Acrobatics check is made as part of another action or as a reaction to a situation.

He should be able to use acrobatics as part of his single "Move" action, note however that

> In addition, you can move through a threatened square without provoking an attack of opportunity from an enemy by using Acrobatics. When moving in this way, you move at half speed. You can move at full speed by increasing the DC of the check by 10.

So he either took the penalty or moved at half speed.

In any case, since he got "past" you using his only available action, he shouldn't be farther than a single move action, and the PC should have no trouble catching up to him.

The only way for him to 'run' away, excluding magic, is for his normal movement speed to be more than twice the PC's speed.

https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/acrobatics.html

Comment: @Ciacciu Thanks! Indeed the creature, being a lamia, had a good speed, hence the quoted 'run'. He also took the DC+10 penalty because of all that creature's bonuses. We had trouble catching up to it (especially my gnome...) but in the end we killed that b*...
Hey I Can Chan is right though, I'd like a global way to understand if something can or cannot be done while nauseated. "*Using* acrobatics" is what I found unclear in the rules to wether it could or could not be used. "Anything requiring attention" is rather vague

Comment: I consider "anything requiring attention" to be descriptive fluff, and "a single move action per turn" to be the actual limitation. Will upgrade the answer accordingly.
@HeyICanChan is this what you were referring to or did I miss something else?

Comment: @Ciacciu Ok, I see. Could you add the location of your Acrobatics definition (i.e. which manual/page?) where it says "Action: None" please? I think that's what I missed

Comment: @HeyICanChan Could you elaborate on you disagreement on this "attention" thing please ^^?

Comment: @Eregrith That line is included in a sentence with other mechanical effects deliberately so that, for example, the DM can look at the player and say, "Dude, you're gonna heave, you just can't [forge the king's signature](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/linguistics.html#linguistics) right now." [*Pathfinder* leaves many things undefined](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/35538/8610), relying on on the DM to make calls at his table. Codifying reality into a legal document is just too much to ask.

Comment: @Eregrith don't have the manuals at hand, the answer has a link to Paizo's site with the definition.

Comment: @Ciacciu and Hey I Can Chan: OK thank you both. I see what it's about now.